# Python K-medoids visualisation

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

This code I get from the internet. I apply to my data and work. So I try to show the visualisation of this method but I can't find the relevant code of visualisation for the k-medoids.

```
from nltk.metrics import distance as distance
import Pycluster as PC
words = ['apple', 'Doppler', 'applaud', 'append', 'barker', 
     'baker', 'bismark', 'park', 'stake', 'steak', 'teak', 'sleek']
dist = [distance.edit_distance(words[i], words[j])
    for i in range(1, len(words))
    for j in range(0, i)]

clusterid, error, nfound = PC.kmedoids(dist, nclusters=3)
cluster = dict()

uniqid=list(set(clusterid))
new_ids = [ uniqid.index(val) for val in clusterid]
for word, label in zip(words, clusterid):
   cluster.setdefault(label, []).append(word)
for label, grp in cluster.items():
    print(grp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input data are *words*.

How would you visualize them? They are not coordinate vectors.

Comment: is there any way to make it work? like levenshtein distance?

Comment: How does that help with visualization? Levenshtein is part of the edit distance family.